# XP Activation - Am I Legal?

Tags: windows, windows-activation, windows-genuine-advantage

Being the family CIO, my girlfriend's mom asked me to fix some problems she was having with her computer - Windows XP Pro.

So, like any good IT guy, after fixing the issue, I made sure to get her computer updated.  She was on SP2.

I installed SP3, rebooted, and got a notification that Windows was not activated.

I called the telephone activation line, entered the code when asked, and then the system asked me how many other computers this copy of Windows is installed on.  I have *no clue* as I didn't build this computer or install it.

I kept saying "I don't know," but it just kept asking me how many.

Finally, frustrated, I typed in "0" to try to get to an operator.  The system apparently interpreted that as me saying it was installed on zero other computers, and gave me a confirmation code.

At this point I was a little frustrated that I couldn't talk to a human, so I went ahead and entered the code it gave me, and it accepted it.

Problem is, I have absolutely no idea if her copy of Windows is legit or not.  So I called the activation line back and got to a representative, and explained the situation exactly the way I explained it above.  He told me that everything is fine and not to worry.

I just thought I'd post this here and see what other people think - should I worry?

Comment: You're asking for *legal advice* from *random strangers on the internet*? *After* you spoke to *a Microsoft representative* and he told you it was okay?

Comment: If it were not okay, the system would have let you know (in a friendly, non-accusatory, up-selling, marketing kind of way) because pirated keys are blacklisted and won’t activate.

Comment: "He told me that everything is fine and not to worry." Good enough for me, its legal, move on.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I guess I just didn't have a lot of faith in Microsoft's tech support, although I'm glad to hear other people have had similar experiences :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At this point I was a little frustrated that I couldn't talk to a
>   human, so I went ahead and entered the code it gave me, **and it
>   accepted it.**
>
> **He told me that everything is fine and not to worry.**

You already answered your own question. If Microsofts system has activated it, and they even told you it was fine, then you have nothing to fear.

> I called the telephone activation line, entered the code when asked,
>   and then the system asked me how many other computers this copy of
>   Windows is installed on. I have no clue as I didn't build this
>   computer or install it.

Happened to me also. It's just a computer thing. If you had a license that was only good for 3 computers are you said 4, it would deny you. I made the error of telling it 9001 and got hung up on. Basically, it's for non-techies to use for the most part, prompting them to get a new Window's license.

**Tl:dr - You have not a fear in the world, fly free.**